# Creating a short, decryptable URL with no back end

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a front-end React application which has no back-end logic. In this application, users can enter data into multiple form fields. I'm wanting to allow users to link directly to the application with their fields filled in based on data stored in the URL. The problem is, I don't know if there's a way of generating a nice looking URL with JavaScript alone.

Ideally I'm wanting the end-result to look something like this:

> http://example.com/#/.../sdf098sdfipodfi0sf3j

...when the user loads up that URL, it should decrypt the string and restore the saved data (how resources like Codepen and JSFiddle allow linking directly to results, but without a back-end or database).

Here's an example of the data I have:

```javascript
{
    "Episodes": [
        {
            "Id":"1",
            "Age":"25",
            "SEX":"1",
            "Diagnosis":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"],
            "Procedure":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
        }
    ]
}
```

There problem I'm having is that there can be:

1. Up to 250 *Episodes*.
2. Up to 999 *Diagnoses* and *Procedures* within each.

The above requirements are absolute extremes and for the most part there will probably only ever be around 5 or 6 *Episodes* each with around 10 *Diagnoses* and 4 or 5 *Procedures*.

If I stringify and then encode the JSON object and stick that in the URL, I'll end up with an incredibly ugly output riddled with `%` symbols:

> http://example.com/#/.../%7B%22Episodes%22:%5B%7B%22Id%22:%221%22,%22Age%22:%2225%22,%22SEX%22:%221%22,%22Diagnosis%22:%5B%221%22,%222%22,%223%22,%224%22,%225%22,%226%22,%227%22,%228%22,%229%22,%2210%22%5D,%22Procedure%22:%5B%221%22,%222%22,%223%22,%224%22,%225%22,%226%22,%227%22,%228%22,%229%22,%2210%22%5D%7D%5D%7D

If I go further and convert that into Base64 using `btoa`, I get something which looks more like a shortened URL, but bearing in mind this is with the demo data I've provided above, this becomes way too long:

> http://example.com/#/.../JTdCJTIyRXBpc29kZXMlMjI6JTVCJTdCJTIySWQlMjI6JTIyMSUyMiwlMjJBZ2UlMjI6JTIyMjUlMjIsJTIyU0VYJTIyOiUyMjElMjIsJTIyRGlhZ25vc2lzJTIyOiU1QiUyMjElMjIsJTIyMiUyMiwlMjIzJTIyLCUyMjQlMjIsJTIyNSUyMiwlMjI2JTIyLCUyMjclMjIsJTIyOCUyMiwlMjI5JTIyLCUyMjEwJTIyJTVELCUyMlByb2NlZHVyZSUyMjolNUIlMjIxJTIyLCUyMjIlMjIsJTIyMyUyMiwlMjI0JTIyLCUyMjUlMjIsJTIyNiUyMiwlMjI3JTIyLCUyMjglMjIsJTIyOSUyMiwlMjIxMCUyMiU1RCU3RCU1RCU3RA==

Is there a nicer way I can condense a lot of information into a relatively small string which would fit nicely in a URL, without any back-end logic?

Ideally I'm wanting a native JavaScript solution, but I appreciate that may not be possible.

Comment: You want a long string to be expressed in a short string. What you're asking for is *compression*, less so an "encoding" or "encryption". You want to try to find a compression algorithm which compresses your data on average while still only using URL-safe characters. That might not exist. You may try to come up with your own serialisation syntax which expresses your data in a more compact way than JSON, especially considering URL-safe characters. Perhaps [Rison](https://github.com/Nanonid/rison) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Can you start by Base64-encoding everything and then come back if you have any problem with such approach?

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk I'm not really sure if that would help. "Episode", for instance, in Base64 becomes "RXBpc29kZQ==", which is 5 characters longer.

Answer (score 1):

How uniform is the data structure?

I can see that with the example you've given above:

```
{
    "Episodes": [
        {
            "Id":"1",
            "Age":"25",
            "SEX":"1",
            "Diagnosis":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"],
            "Procedure":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
        }
    ]
}
```

You could reconstruct that with:

```
http://example.com/#/.../E1I1A25S1D10P10
```

But that's still a 15-character shortcode for 1 episode... so if there were 6 episodes, that would increase to around 90 characters.